# Safari not picking up CSS variable updated by React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, safari

I am using CSS Animations to create animations for a vertical image reel in my React app, however, the animation uses a variable that gets set in CSS by Javascript using the setProperty function.

So essentially, I have a fixed size reel with 10 slides and each slide has it's own animation (this is to handle where the image starts).

```
$margin: 25px;
$max-images-in-view: 10;
$speed: 90;
$offset: calc($speed * 1000ms);

.slide {
   
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: #{$speed}s;

  @for $i from 1 through 10 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation-delay: calc(
        1000ms * $speed/$max-images-in-view * (#{$i} + 1) - $offset
      );
      animation-name: slide-animation-#{$i};
      top: 100%;

      @keyframes slide-animation-#{$i} {
        from {
          top: 100%;
          opacity: 1;
        }
          
        to {
          top: calc(
            100% - $max-images-in-view * (var(--image-reel-image-height) + $margin)
          );
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `--image-reel-image-height` variable gets set by the react component upon load and after the screen size updates.

```
  const calculateCSSImageHeight = () => {
    const imgEl = document.getElementsByClassName(Styles.imageContainer).item(0)

    if (isBrowser)
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
        '--image-reel-image-height',
        `${imgEl?.clientHeight ?? 0}px`
      )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateCSSImageHeight()
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') window.addEventListener('resize', calculateCSSImageHeight)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', calculateCSSImageHeight)
    }
  })
```

This seems to work perfectly fine for Chrome, but Safari doesn't seem to regenerate/update the animation after the component updates the CSS variable. For example, if I set `--image-reel-height` to '300px' as a default value, it animates as though the image height is 300px but the animation never updates after the variable has been updated.

Why isn't Safari picking up the CSS variable changes?